# How do I make a function out of these sql statements so I dont have to repeat them so many times?

Tags: php, mysql, function

I would like to make these statements into a function instead, as you see its kind of repetitive. How would you make this more efficient using a function? Very grateful for tips!

```
if (isset ($_GET["news"])){

$statement = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM posts INNER JOIN users ON 
posts.userID = users.id
WHERE category = 'news'");
$statement->execute();
$blog = $statement ->fetchALL(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

}

if (isset ($_GET["style"])){

$statement = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM posts INNER JOIN users ON 
posts.userID = users.id
WHERE category = 'style'");
$statement->execute();
$blog = $statement ->fetchALL(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

}

if (isset ($_GET["interior"])){

$statement = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM posts INNER JOIN users ON 
posts.userID = users.id
WHERE category = 'interior'");
$statement->execute();
$blog = $statement ->fetchALL(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

}

if (isset ($_GET["featured"])){

$statement = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM posts INNER JOIN users ON 
posts.userID = users.id
WHERE category = 'featured'");
$statement->execute();
$blog = $statement ->fetchALL(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

}
```

Its based on a category sorting(news, style, interior, featured).

Comment: With my class [GrumpyPDO](https://github.com/GrumpyCrouton/GrumpyPDO), each of these queries would only be one line each.  `$statement = $db->all("QUERY")`

Comment: We are always glad to help and support new coders but ***you need to help yourself first. :-)*** After [**doing more research**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527) if you have a problem **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of ways to skin this cat, but I use a function from which I can run all queries with PDO. Here is that function, along with the connection:

```
function dataQuery($query, $params) {
    // what kind of query is this?
    $queryType = explode(' ', $query);

    // establish database connection
    try {
        $dbh = new PDO(DBL, USER, PASS);
        $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
        $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    }
    catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
        $errorCode = $e->getCode();
    }

    // run query
    try {
        $queryResults = $dbh->prepare($query);
        $result = $queryResults->execute($params);
        if($queryResults != null && 'SELECT' == $queryType[0]) {
            // only return results for SELECT queries - the remainder need no output
            $results = $queryResults->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            return $results;
        }

        $queryResults = null; // first of the two steps to properly close
        $dbh = null; // second step to close the connection
        return $result;
    }
    catch(PDOException $e) {
        $errorMsg = $e->getMessage();
        echo $errorMsg;
    }
}
```

NOTE: The `try/catch` is not necessary but I do capture the error messages for other pruposes, so this is a handy way of doing it.

Then, any time I need to query I can just write the query and send the parameters with the request:

```
$role = $_POST['role'];
$getRoleID = "SELECT `id` FROM `roles` WHERE `role` = :role;";
$params = array(':role'=>$role);
$result = dataQuery($getRoleID, $params);
```

However, your's is a little more specific. You want a single function for your blog. Combining yours with mine you could do this:

```
function getBlogPosts($type) {

    $getPosts = "SELECT * FROM posts INNER JOIN users ON posts.userID = users.id WHERE category = :category");
    $params = array(':category'=>$type);
    $result = dataQuery($getPosts, $params);
    return $result;
}
```

Now, to call the function you just have to insert the type of posts you want:

```
$featured = getBlogPosts('featured');
```

or:

```
$interior = getBlogPosts('interior');
```

Parse the returned results and you're well on your way.